# Cyclic dependency is forcing me to split service and factory depending on state. Is it ok?

Tags: java, javafx, software-design, cyclic-reference, cyclic-dependency

I am creating a JavaFX desktop application using the MVVM pattern. Each `View` requires a `ViewModel`. Instead of using `ViewA viewA = new ViewA(new ViewModelA());`, I decided to abstract it using the factory pattern.

The ViewFactory constructor has arguments for other services which the view models need. For example, a part of my application is showing all the collections of images stored in a database, corresponding to the `CollectionsView` and `CollectionsViewModel`. To retrieve all the images and collections from the database, I have created a `CollectionService`, which gets passed to the ViewFactory.

The code:

```
public interface CollectionService {
    List<ImageCollectionItem> getAllImagesForCollection(Collection collection);
    List<Collection> getAllCollections();
}

public class CollectionsView extends View<CollectionsViewModel> {
    public CollectionsView(CollectionsViewModel model) { ... }
}

public class CollectionsViewModel implements ViewModel {
    public CollectionsViewModel(CollectionService collectionService) {
        collections.set(collectionService.getAllCollections());
    }
}

public class ViewFactory {
    public ViewFactory(CollectionService collectionService) { ... }

    public CollectionsView createCollectionsView() {
        return new CollectionsView(new CollectionsViewModel(collectionService));
    }
}
```

So far all great. The problem starts with another `View`, the `ConnectView`, which is basically a database selection screen with a connect button at the bottom. When the connect button is pressed, the view should change to the main one, let's say `CollectionsView` for simplicity.

To abstract it a bit, I created a `ConnectionManager` interface (I know the name is not the best but I couldn't think of a better one. Maybe `ConnectionNotifier`?) with basically one method that indicates that a new connection to a database has been made and gets passed the corresponding SQL `Connection` instance.

The code:

```
public class ConnectView { ... }

public class ConnectViewModel {
    public ConnectViewModel(ConnectionManager connectionManager, ...)

    public onConnectPress() {
        // check database exists, valid schema, etc
        // create connection
        connectionManager.connected(newConnection);
    }
}

public interface ConnectionManager {
    void connected(Connection connection);
}
```

Now in the implementation of the `ConnectionManager`, when `connected` is called, the services that need a database are instantiated and the view on the screen changes to `CollectionsView`.

For that I created a new class called `NavigationService` which creates the view using the `ViewFactory` and sets it as the one on screen.

The code:

```
public class NavigationService {
    public NavigationService(ViewFactory viewFactory, ...) { ... }

    public void goToCollectionsView() {
        CollectionsView colView = viewFactory.createCollectionsView();
        // set colView on screen
    }
}

ConnectionManager connectionManagerImpl = connection -> {
    // create services that need connection (CollectionService, ...)
    navigator.goToCollectionsView();
}
```

Again, everything is working good. But what if I have an aditional `View` that doesn't require a connected state? Maybe a help button on the connect screen which should create a `HelpView`? How do I go back to the connect screen? To add a `goToConnectView()` in navigator I would have to pass it the `ConnectionManager` to create the view, which in turn requires the navigator.

So to create the `ConnectionManager`, I need the `NavigatorService` and vice versa.

The solutions I have thought about:

1. Create the connection manager without the navigator, create the navigator and then just use a setter.
2. Create the connection manager without the navigator, create the navigator and use the listener pattern to call the navigator when a new connection is made.
3. Split the navigator in `ConnectedStateNavigatorService` and `NotConnectedStateNavigator`, which in turn requires to split the view factory in `ConnectedStateViewFactory` and `NotConnectedStateViewFactory`.

I don't like option 1 because I don't want to depend on an extra statement, just seems dirty.

I don't like option 2 too because this kind of execution flow with listeners, events etc seems to me more appropriate for C# instead, doesn't feel like the correct choice for Java. And again, I have to rely on the extra `addListener` call.

While I don't like option 3, this is the one I went with. But again it just doesn't feel right. The code is starting to get cluttered with services, factories which I have coded as interfaces in my application, meaning that there is the extra class for the implementation of each.

My question is: Do you think this is ok?

Note: I don't want to use the mvvmFX framework because I don't like all the magic and also relying on reflection too much.

(Sorry for my English but I am not a native speaker)

Comment: "*I don't like option 2 too because this kind of execution flow with listeners, events etc seems to me more appropriate for C# instead, doesn't feel like the correct choice for Java*" - Both Java and C# support functional paradigms. Using listeners/callbacks isn't a C# thing. [Callbacks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) are common in any language, including Java. Using callbacks can be very useful, and if they work for your requirements, there should be no reason to avoid them.

Comment: You're asking a purely opinion-based question (which is frowned upon here at Stack Overflow) but I'll offer my opinion anyway: this is probably the most complicated and stress-inducing model I've seen a programmer use in a long time. Granted, I'm a fairly new programmer myself, but I still think you're overthinking the process quite a bit.

Comment: @Zephyr The thing is I actually enjoy thinking about things like that and that's what I like in programming in general. I understand that it would not be good for time management in a job environment but for me it's a hobby. And yeah, I see that it's kind of an opinion based question but I am not sure where else I could post this. I often have these type of questions that are difficult to find specific answers with Google and there is not really anyone I know that I can just bounce off thoughts for things I am not completely sure about. SO is generally my last option if I am stuck for a while.

Comment: @VinceEmigh After some thinking I agree with you. If you want, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!